# why this ajax php poll Undefined index: poll?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

why i see this error message "( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: poll in D:\wamp\www\poll\poll.php on line 6" in the ajax when i try to poll .. i have two files

1- index.html contains get request

2- poll.php file to select request and display result

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>AJAX Poll Using jQuery and PHP</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
    var loader=$('#loader');
    var pollcontainer=$('#pollcontainer');
    loader.fadeIn();
    //Load the poll form
    $.get('poll.php', '', function(data, status){
        pollcontainer.html(data);
        animateResults(pollcontainer);
        pollcontainer.find('#viewresult').click(function(){
            //if user wants to see result
            loader.fadeIn();
            $.get('poll.php', 'result=1', function(data,status){
                pollcontainer.fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    $(this).html(data);
                    animateResults(this);
                });
                loader.fadeOut();
            });
            //prevent default behavior
            return false;
        }).end()
        .find('#pollform').submit(function(){
            var selected_val=$(this).find('input[name=poll]:checked').val();
            if(selected_val!=''){
                //post data only if a value is selected
                loader.fadeIn();
                $.post('poll.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data, status){
                    $('#formcontainer').fadeOut(100, function(){
                        $(this).html(data);
                        animateResults(this);
                        loader.fadeOut();
                    });
                });
            }
            //prevent form default behavior
            return false;
        });
        loader.fadeOut();
    });

    function animateResults(data){
        $(data).find('.bar').hide().end().fadeIn('slow', function(){
                            $(this).find('.bar').each(function(){
                                var bar_width=$(this).css('width');
                                $(this).css('width', '0').animate({ width: bar_width }, 1000);
                            });
                        });
    }

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" >
        <h1>User Poll</h1>
        <div id="pollcontainer" >
        </div>
        <p id="loader" >Loading...</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

poll.php

```
  <?php
    //Update database information according to your server settings
    $conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Can't connect to mysql host");
    //Select the database to use
    mysql_select_db('ahmed') or die("Can't connect to DB");
    if(!$_POST['poll'] || !$_POST['pollid']){
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT id, ques FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            //display question
            echo "<p class=\"pollques\" >".$row['ques']."</p>";
            $poll_id=$row['id'];
        }
        if($_GET["result"]==1 || $_COOKIE["voted".$poll_id]=='yes'){
            //if already voted or asked for result
            showresults($poll_id);
            exit;
        }
        else{
        //display options with radio buttons
            $query=mysql_query("SELECT id, value FROM options WHERE ques_id=$poll_id");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
                echo '<div id="formcontainer" ><form method="post" id="pollform" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" >';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="pollid" value="'.$poll_id.'" />';
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    echo '<p><input type="radio" name="poll" value="'.$row['id'].'" id="option-'.$row['id'].'" /> 
                    <label for="option-'.$row['id'].'" >'.$row['value'].'</label></p>';
                }
                echo '<p><input type="submit"  value="Submit" /></p></form>';
                echo '<p><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?result=1" id="viewresult">View result</a></p></div>';
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if($_COOKIE["voted".$_POST['pollid']]!='yes'){

            //Check if selected option value is there in database?
            $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM options WHERE id='".intval($_POST["poll"])."'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
                $query="INSERT INTO votes(option_id, voted_on, ip) VALUES('".$_POST["poll"]."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')";
                if(mysql_query($query))
                {
                    //Vote added to database
                    setcookie("voted".$_POST['pollid'], 'yes', time()+86400*300);               
                }
                else
                    echo "There was some error processing the query: ".mysql_error();
            }
        }
        showresults(intval($_POST['pollid']));
    }
    function showresults($poll_id){
        global $conn;
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as totalvotes FROM votes WHERE option_id IN(SELECT id FROM options WHERE ques_id='$poll_id')");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            $total=$row['totalvotes'];
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT options.id, options.value, COUNT(*) as votes FROM votes, options WHERE votes.option_id=options.id AND votes.option_id IN(SELECT id FROM options WHERE ques_id='$poll_id') GROUP BY votes.option_id");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $percent=round(($row['votes']*100)/$total);
            echo '<div class="option" ><p>'.$row['value'].' (<em>'.$percent.'%, '.$row['votes'].' votes</em>)</p>';
            echo '<div class="bar ';
            if($_POST['poll']==$row['id']) echo ' yourvote';
            echo '" style="width: '.$percent.'%; " ></div></div>';
        }
        echo '<p>Total Votes: '.$total.'</p>';
    }
```

Comment: Are you positive the path to your poll.php is correct?

Comment: @RickCalder path is correct. else he would have got Object not found error or similiar. @user1080247: `isset` wont solve any issue in your case. Because you are NOT sending any data in the ajax request or even if you are sending, your name attribute in those forms are different. If you want to get the results, see what data is being sent in the header on chrome developer tool or firebug. Then do the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 6 of `poll.php` from:

```
if(!$_POST['poll'] || !$_POST['pollid']){
```

to:

```
if(!isset($_POST['poll']) || !isset($_POST['pollid'])){
```

As written, it assumes the existence of `$_POST['poll']` and is conditioned on its value being `null`, `false` or `0`.  In the case where the value simply does not exist, the error that you are seeing is the result.  The solution is to confirm that the variable has been set at all using `isset()`.

Also, change line 15 from:

```
if($_GET["result"]==1 || $_COOKIE["voted".$poll_id]=='yes'){
```

to

```
if((isset($_GET["result"]) && $_GET["result"] == 1) || (isset($_COOKIE["voted"  .$poll_id]) && $_COOKIE["voted" . $poll_id] == 'yes')){
```

Similarly, as written, it assumes the existence of `$_GET['result']` and is conditioned on its value being `1`.  In the case where the value simply does not exist, the error that you are seeing is the result.  The solution is again to first confirm that the variable has been set at all using `isset()` and then check its value.

---

See:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: thanks but i still see this message " Notice: Undefined index: result in D:\wamp\www\poll\ajax-poll\poll.php on line 15"

Comment: Same issue, second occurance (notice the different line number) -- I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
if(!$_POST['poll'] || !$_POST['pollid']){
```

to

```
if(!isset($_POST['poll']) || !isset($_POST['pollid'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

When your page sends a GET request to poll.php with no request data, it hits line 6 and tries to evaluate $_POST['poll']. Except there's no 'poll' key in the $_POST array at that point, and so you get that error. **Use isset() to test for the existence of array keys BEFORE you try to evaluate them**. If you wanted to test both the existence of a key and that it was set to something the evaluates to `true`, then you might write:

```
if(isset($_POST['poll']) && $_POST['poll']){
    /*...code...*/
}
```

It's okay to evaluate $_POST['poll'] after the `&&` because it will stop evaluating if the isset() returns false.

Also, I noticed that, in at least one case, you are putting $_POST data directly into a mysql query. [Don't do that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

This kind of processing is so common I use a support function to make it worry-free; it does three things: 1) returns `null` with no notices/errors if the key doesn't exist 2) escapes strings to prevent SQL injection if the value does exist 3) does some optional type casting, which is nice for booleans and such. Then I can write with this pattern:

```
$poll_id = $Input->get('poll_id', Input::INT);

if($poll_id) { /* do stuff */ }
```